# How to change the serialization method used by the multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, python-multiprocessing

How can I change the serialization method used by the Python `multiprocessing` library? In particular, the default serialization method uses the `pickle` library with the default pickle protocol version for that version of Python. The default pickle protocol is version 2 in Python 2.7 and version 3 in Python 3.6. How can I set the protocol version to 2 in Python 3.6, so I can use some of the classes (like `Client` and `Listener`) in the `multiprocessing` library to communicate between a server processing run by Python 2.7 and a client process run by Python 3.6?

(Side note: as a test, I modified [line 206 of `multiprocessing/connection.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5458647bb867770fc3d830a618cef6994fdfac4b/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L206) by adding `protocol=2` to the `dump()` call to force the protocol version to 2 and my client/server processes worked in my limited testing with the server run by 2.7 and the client by 3.6).

In Python 3.6, a [patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue28053) was merged to let the serializer be set, but the patch was undocumented, and I haven't figured out how to use it. Here is how I tried to use it (I posted this also to the Python ticket that I linked to):

pickle2reducer.py:

```
from multiprocessing.reduction import ForkingPickler, AbstractReducer

class ForkingPickler2(ForkingPickler):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 1:
            args[1] = 2
        else:
            args.append(2)
        super().__init__(*args)

    @classmethod
    def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=2):
        return ForkingPickler.dumps(obj, protocol)


def dump(obj, file, protocol=2):
    ForkingPickler2(file, protocol).dump(obj)


class Pickle2Reducer(AbstractReducer):
    ForkingPickler = ForkingPickler2
    register = ForkingPickler2.register
    dump = dump
```

and in my client:

```
import pickle2reducer
multiprocessing.reducer = pickle2reducer.Pickle2Reducer()
```

at the top before doing anything else with `multiprocessing`. I still see `ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3` on the server run by Python 2.7 when I do this.

Comment: There is a pending PR for said issue (http://bugs.python.org/issue28053)
to add documentation and improvements.

https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15058/files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the patch you're referring to works if you're using a multiprocessing ["context" object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods).

Using your pickle2reducer.py, your client should start with:

```
import pickle2reducer
import multiprocessing as mp

ctx = mp.get_context()
ctx.reducer = pickle2reducer.Pickle2Reducer()
```

And `ctx` has the same API as  `multiprocessing`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That seems like the right way to make use of the patch. I don't see how to use a context in my specific situation. I use `from multiprocessing.connection import Client, Listener` and `from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NameSpaceProxy` and none of those four classes are accessible from the context object. I was able to do this instead: `multiprocessing.context._default_context.reducer = Pickle2Reducer()`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much for this. It led me exactly to the solution I needed. I ended up doing something similar but by modifying the Connection class. It felt cleaner to me than making my own full subclass and replacing that.

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection, _ForkingPickler, Client, Listener

def send_py2(self, obj):
    self._check_closed()
    self._check_writable()
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj, protocol=2))

Connection.send = send_py2
```

This is just exactly the code from multiprocessing.connection with only the `protocol=2` argument added.

I suppose you could even do the same thing by directly editing the original `ForkingPickler` class inside of multiprocessing.reduction.

Comment: There is a syntax error at the third line in the function, you forgot a close parenthesis in `self._send_bytes`

Comment: Thanks! That's what happens when you copy and paste carelessly. Just updated it.