# Working with Python2 and Python3 in the same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My main app is running with Python3

I have a crucial package that I need to install which only support Python2...

I'm running on windows

I thought of maybe setting this package on another virtual environment in addition to a flask server to be used for communication.

Is there another way to pipe messages between apps beside a server?

Is there a better way to go for Python2, Python3 mix?

Comment: maybe ask about the packages you're using... there might be alternatives to the package or maybe alternatives to the packages that are forcing you to use python 3

Answer (score 6):

How about using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. You can start the Python 2 program as a subprocess of your Python 3 app. They can communicate via the subprocess PIPE.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is too heavy. Why not use socket and selectors?  [offical example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/selectors.html#selectors.EpollSelector)

Comment: is your answer to this question?

Comment: In my opinion, just building a socket for send&receive message is convenient and light way which communicate between Python2 and Python3.

Comment: was just confused why you implied OP uses flask

Comment: oh, I see in the middle now

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I got the similar problem lately and would like to share my solution. I used [multiprocssing.connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.connection) module. The default pickling protocol should be changed when sending the data from Python 3 to Python 2. The way to change the default pickling protocol is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68229349/919930).