# Submit dynamically loaded functions to the ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I want to submit a dynamically loaded functions to the  `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. Here is the example. There is `module.py` which contains the function.

```py
# Content of module.py

def func():
    return 1
```

And then, there is the rest in `file.py`

```py
# Content of file.py

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import multiprocessing
import importlib
from pathlib import Path
import inspect


def load_function_from_module(path):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(path.stem, str(path))
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)

    return mod


def func_top_level():
    return 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Dynamically load function from other module.
    path = Path(__file__).parent / "module.py"
    func = dict(inspect.getmembers(load_function_from_module(path)))["func"]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(func)
        future_ = executor.submit(func_top_level)

    # Here comes the exception.
    print(future.result())
```

The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function func at 0x7f5a548eb050>: it's not the same object as module.func
```

**Solution 1: Wrapping `func` with top-level function**

Place `def myfunc(): return func()` after the function is loaded and submit `myfunc`.

This works for this example, but as soon as you move the whole `if __name__ ...` block into its own `main()` function, `myfunc()` becomes local again and the hack does not work. Since the problem occurs deep down in my application, this is not possible.

**Attempt 2: Replacing `pickle` with `cloudpickle`**

My personal favourite for a solution would be to change the way `ProcessPoolExecutor` serializes objects. For example, `cloudpickle` can serialize `func`.

Although, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45316233/7523785) suggests that it is possible to register a custom reducer, the following PRs and issues suggest the feature does not work or I am just unable to replace `pickle` with `cloudpickle`.

- https://bugs.python.org/issue28053
- https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9959
- https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15058

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a simple wrapper class to patch `cloudpickle` into `ProcessPoolExecutor`, like so:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import cloudpickle

def apply_cloudpickle(fn, /, *args, **kwargs):
    fn = cloudpickle.loads(fn)
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

class CloudpickleProcessPoolExecutor(ProcessPoolExecutor):
    def submit(self, fn, /, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().submit(apply_cloudpickle, cloudpickle.dumps(fn), *args, **kwargs)
```

Then when you call `.map` and other methods, `cloudpickle` will be pickling the function object under the hood. (Note that arguments will still run through the ordinary `pickle` pipeline.)

(The same strategy works with `dill` etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can only add that positional-only arguments (before `/` in the signature) are a Python 3.8+ feature. For Python 3.7, remove the forward slash. If you are using type checking on a newer version, add `type: ignore[override]` to ignore the mismatch of the signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with cloudpickle. Start with the contents of the two files. Then, move the body under `if __name__ ...` to a new function `main()`. This makes the problem harder because the first solution will not work.

Since pickle cannot serialize the dynamically imported function `func()` from `module.py`, we serialize the function with cloudpickle to bytes in the main process. Then, we will submit a function which accepts the bytes and deserializes the function. Then, the function can be executed. These two functions are changed or added:

```py
import cloudpickle


def main():
    # Dynamically load function from other module.
    path = Path(__file__).parent / "module.py"
    func = dict(inspect.getmembers(load_function_from_module(path)))["func"]

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
        bytes_ = cloudpickle.dumps(func)
        future = executor.submit(deserialize_and_execute, bytes_)
        future_ = executor.submit(func_top_level)

    # Here comes the exception.
    print(future.result())


def deserialize_and_execute(bytes_):
    func = cloudpickle.loads(bytes_)
    func()
```